# Regular Expression for removing WordPress attachments in database

Tags: sql, regex, wordpress, attachment

I had to move my WordPress site over and did some house cleaning of the media and then ran a plugin to reinsert the cleaned media into the database. The way it did this however is by looking at the directory, so now instead of just having file: xyz.jpg, I have xyz-150x150, xyz-200x200, etc. I want to run a regular expression on my sql to remove all attachments that have _wp_attached_file and then they follow the following naming scheme "name-" "sizes". For example:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` VALUES(2379, 2152, '_wp_attached_file', '2010/09/Oneonta-Gorge-leaves-150x150.jpg');
```

This entire line would be deleted but the one that looks like this would remain:

```
INSERT INTO `wp_postmeta` VALUES(2379, 2152, '_wp_attached_file', '2010/09/Oneonta-Gorge-leaves.jpg');
```

Also, if you think it would just be easier to remove the -200x200 for example and then run another script to remove duplicate lines, that works too. The different dimensions I have are:

- 150x150
- 200x200
- 200x300
- 300x189

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something you can try. This first query will select all the images with the dimension suffix. This is just for sanity checking the query to make sure you're selecting the images that you want.

```
select * from wp_postmeta where meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' and meta_value regexp  '.+-[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{3}\.(jpg|gif|png)$'
```

If you're satisfied with the results you can run the delete query:

```
delete from wp_postmeta where meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' and meta_value regexp  '.+-[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{3}\.(jpg|gif|png)$'
```

Alternatively you could use `LIKE`. You'd have to run it for each dimension. This query also assumes a three character extension, such as gif, jpg, or png.

```
select * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' and meta_value LIKE '%-150x150.___'
```

Comment: LOL. What a brilliant move. I'll give it a go and let you know!

Comment: That worked great - 1700 rows deleted. Thanks for the help as always!

Comment: Acutally that didn't fully fix it, the media gallery is actually pulled from wp_posts as well. So I ran the following queries:

    SELECT * from wp_posts WHERE post_title regexp '.+-[0-9]{3}x[0-9]{3}\$';

Notice I removed the extensions since this information is stored in the title and don't contain them. Then I ran the same query only deleting them this time.